# Lazarus Ctrl Space jumping to uses section

Tags: shortcut, lazarus

in Lazarus, Ctrl + Space should show the code complement, but in my case, sometimes it jumps to use sections. How can I stop this jump and force always show these complements?

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour. Afaict, it is quite consistent, not random: if I am typing an object name but have not got as far as typing the ., Ctrl-Space takes me to the end of the interface Uses section; if I press Ctrl-Space after I type the., it pops up the code-completion box.  I'm not sure if this behaviour is intentional - I suggest you try asking in the Lazarus user group: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org

Comment: Hi, tks for your help. For me this seems random and not intentional.